# Error Spotting :Whenever you are coming here, you bring a lot of sweets for me

Tags: exam-questions

> Whenever (A)/ you are coming here,(B)/ you bring a lot of sweets for me.(C)

This is an error correction question. But I think that this is a bad question because it can be interpreted in two ways.

**1.** As per my book it says since its a routine habit I need to replace **you are coming** in part *B* with **you come** [*Whenever you come here, you bring a lot of sweets for me.* ]

But I interpret it in a different way, 
**2.** I am correcting it just by removing **you** from part *C* which conveys a meaning that I am saying the above sentence to any XYZ asking him to bring a lot of sweets for me whenever ( any day , today , tomorrow or whenever) he comes at my place. [ *Whenever you are coming here, bring a lot of sweets for me*.]

Am I correct ?

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever you are coming here, bring a lot of sweets for me.

That is a grammatical utterance. A possible context would be a back-and-forth about when a person was going to arrive:

> You're coming here next week, right?
>   --No, I arrive in two weeks.
>   You emailed a few days ago, saying you would arrive before month end.
>   --Yes, but I sent a follow-up saying my plans had changed.
>   Well, **whenever you're coming here**, bring me some sweets.

There, **whenever** has a different meaning, as I think you know. It doesn't mean "at all times, every time" but "whatever time it happens to be".

Comment: I meant to say the same thing but perhaps couldn't explain it properly in question. I have edited it now, hope it's clear now.

Comment: @user212388: I was agreeing with you. ("whatever time it happens to be ~= "today, tomorrow, next week...whenever".

Comment: But your answer doesn't answer my question, I was asking if I am  correct or not ? Are both the interpretations correct way to correct this sentience  ?

Comment: @user212388: You need to read more carefully. My response does answer your question. It addresses the "correction" your proposed and states that the result would be a grammatical utterance.

Answer (score 0):

The analysis in 1. is correct. Then:

> Whenever you come here, **you bring a lot of sweets** for me.

Based on when the action (the visit) occurs, the result is "you bring a lot of sweets for me". It is a fact.

But you want to write:

> Whenever you come here, **bring a lot of sweets** for me.

Now "bring a lot of sweets for me" is actually a request. We have no idea if any sweets will actually be delivered.

Your change is changing the meaning of the sentence.